# Filter/Query support in Elasticsearch Top hits Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch documentation states that `The top_hits aggregation returns regular search hits, because of this many per hit features can be supported` Crucially, the list includes `Named filters and queries`

But trying to add any filter or query throws `SearchParseException: Unknown key for a START_OBJECT`

Use case: I have items which have list of nested comments

items{id} -> comments {date, rating}

I want to get top rated comment for each item in the last week.

```
{
 "query": {
   "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "items": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "comment": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_comment": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                //need filter  here to select only comments of last week
                "sort": {
                  "comments.rating": {
                    "order": "desc"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So is the documentation wrong, or is there any way to add a filter?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: could you post your query and some sample documents and desired output?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 updated the question

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have mapped them as `Nested`? I've just tried to execute such query on my data and it did work fine.

If so, you could simply add a filter aggregation, right after nested aggregation (hopefully I haven't messed up curly brackets):

```
POST data/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "comments",
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "comments.date": {
                "gte": "now-1w",
                "lte": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "items": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filterComments": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "comments.date": {
                    "gte": "now-1w",
                    "lte": "now"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "topComments": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": {
                      "comments.rating": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. Always include FULL path for nested objects.

So this query will:

1. Filter documents that have comments younger than one week to narrow down documents for aggregation and to find those, who actually have such comments (filtered query)
2. Do terms aggregation based on id field
3. Open nested sub documents (comments)
4. Filter them by date
5. Return the most badass one (most rated)

Comment: I know a filter agg can be used followed by a top hit, but the question was about filter inside a top hit and probable wrong documentation of the same.

Comment: @Summit even if it was, you didn't write that question is about filters in top hits aggregation. You asked how to get top rated comments for each item in the last week. That's what this query will do.

Comment: Its reasonable to believe that you missed the whole subject and first part of the question, while answering. Even so, even after being informed that the answer completely misses what was asked, your persistant misinterpretation of it is rather distasteful.

Comment: @Summit quoting you : *So is the documentation wrong, or is there any way to add a filter?* that's the only way to add a filter. Simple as that. You didn't specify that filter has to be inside top hits aggregation. Be clear with your questions next time.

Comment: Did you read the said documentation, or the subject or the first half of the question, or anything except this line? First read question/subject before answering next time, or better yet, don't take the trouble of answering itself. This conversation is already beyond the realm of rationality, anyway.